# Как восстановить БД PostgreSQL из скрипта с помощью командной строки

Tags: postgresql, cmd, dump, dbeaver

Я в этом новичок и не знаю, с чего начать. У меня есть скрипт .sql, postgreSQL dump, из которого нужно восстановить БД. Через UI Dveaver не получается, размер файла около 100МБ, программа виснет. Как обратиться к Dveaver через cmd, или нужно установить другую СУБД? Подскажите отправную точку, пожалуйста, что-то зависла с этой проблемой.

Comment: Первым приходит на ум, разбить файл на несколько отдельных, которые ваша UI сможет обработать. Хотя делить файл на части можно не в произвольных местах, а там, где очередной запрос отработал. а новый ещё и не думал начинаться. И скормить системе все файлы последовательно.

Comment: [Restoring the Dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup-dump.html#BACKUP-DUMP-RESTORE)